# Is there a way to change the text cursor color in macOS Sonoma?

Tags: macos, sonoma

Sonoma seems to be a pretty nice release overall so far. But in this version they changed the text cursor/I beam to match the accent color selected in System Settings > Appearance.

This has proven to be very distracting for me. Anyone happen to know if I can change it back to a neutral black without changing the accent color everywhere else?

(The settings in Accessibility > Display > Pointer only changes the non-text cursor color)

Comment: Found anything out yet? This is also driving me nuts, such a distraction.

Comment: Still looking. If I find a solution, I promise to post it here as well :)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77248249/disable-macos-sonoma-text-insertion-point-cursor-caps-lock-indicator

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, @slaakso!

Comment: I can confirm that the excellent solution proposed over on StackOverflow does indeed work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77256214/869134.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned on SE, you can just do:

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/FeatureFlags/Domain/UIKit.plist redesigned_text_cursor -dict-add Enabled -bool NO
```

The folders will be created if not existing.

You will need a restart.

Comment: This does indeed work, but as noted in some of the commentary there, this will break some text entry fields in apps which have custom cursor handling. For example, as of the time I write this comment, the cursor is entirely invisible when using [Ulysses](https://ulysses.app) if you have set this flag, so your mileage may vary with how usable this is or is not.

Comment: A workaround for Ulysses, Alfred, is to disable the new cursor and use Hammerspoon to draw our own custom cursor in specific apps: https://www.alfredforum.com/topic/21080-alfred-doesnt-show-the-text-cursor-in-macos-sonoma-if-the-redesigned-text-cursor-is-disabled/?do=findComment&comment=109419